# Can a WordPress theme, broke if I'm using custom classes in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a serious question about custom CSS in WordPress. I'm creating websites in WordPress based on themes. However, I'm using custom html/CSS (no js) blocks in which I'm not using the theme's classes, but I create my own classes.

So the question is if custom classes can affect a future theme update and a website might break.

Comment: No, if you are using Html design blocks and adding your code this will not affect anything.

Comment: Please check this https://www.quora.com/Will-upgrading-WordPress-break-your-website

Comment: Yes, that could happen. That's what updates are for